# How run multiple consecutive GIMP batch commands without quitting GIMP for each one?

Tags: python, bash, shell, gimp, gimpfu

Is there a way to run these GIMP batch commands from a bash shell script or python script one right after another without quitting GIMP after each one?

```
#!/bin/bash

gimp -i -b '(python-fu-dgm-batch-create RUN-NONINTERACTIVE "ABC3-" "dgmconfig.xml" "b2aa" "PMDC" "bmp")' -b **'(gimp-quit 0)'**
gimp -i -b '(python-fu-dgm-batch-create RUN-NONINTERACTIVE "ABC3-" "dgmconfig.xml" "b2ab" "PMDC" "bmp")' -b **'(gimp-quit 0)'**
gimp -i -b '(python-fu-dgm-batch-create RUN-NONINTERACTIVE "ABC3-" "dgmconfig.xml" "b2ac" "PMDC" "bmp")' -b **'(gimp-quit 0)'**
gimp -i -b '(python-fu-dgm-batch-create RUN-NONINTERACTIVE "ABC3-" "dgmconfig.xml" "b2ad" "PMDC" "bmp")' -b **'(gimp-quit 0)'**
```

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed the part in parenthesis

-b, --batch=   Batch command to run (can be used multiple times)

This works for me

```
#!/bin/bash

gimp -i -b '(python-fu-dgm-batch-create RUN-NONINTERACTIVE "ABC3-" "dgmconfig.xml" "b2aa" "PMDC" "bmp")' \
-b '(python-fu-dgm-batch-create RUN-NONINTERACTIVE "ABC3-" "dgmconfig.xml" "b2ab" "PMDC" "bmp")' \
-b '(python-fu-dgm-batch-create RUN-NONINTERACTIVE "ABC3-" "dgmconfig.xml" "b2ac" "PMDC" "bmp")' \
-b '(python-fu-dgm-batch-create RUN-NONINTERACTIVE "ABC3-" "dgmconfig.xml" "b2ad" "PMDC" "bmp")' \
-b '(gimp-quit 0)'
```

Sorry if I hope I didn't waste any ones time.